# Proving the additive inverse of a sum is the sum of the additive inverses

Tags: arithmetic

I have this proposition to prove: For all $m, n, \in\mathbb Z$: $-(m + n) = (-m) + (-n)$
Proof:
\begin{align*}
-(m + n) + (m + n) &= 0 + 0\\
-(m + n) + (m + n) &= (-m) + m + (-n) + n\\
(-m) + (-n) + -(m + n) + m + n &= (-m) + (-n) + m + (-m) + (-n) + n\\
-(m + n) &= (-m) + (-n)
\end{align*}

What do you think? I am a bit unsure when I go from (m + n) to m + n (remove the parentheses). Thank you!

Comment: Yes that proof works!

Comment: An effective answer or confirmation entirely depends on what axioms you are allowed to assume (or results, etc.).

Comment: You can go from ..+(m+n) to ..+m+n. Both mean same thing. Else prove $$a+(m+n)=a+m+n$$. which is there in associativity property of addition.

Comment: @Hi Harish! Yes, I worked it out: 
\begin{align*}
(m + n) &= 0 + (m + n)\\
(m + n) &= (0 + m) + n\\
(m + n) &= (m) + n\\
(m + n) &= m + n\\
\end{align*}

Comment: @induktio I am only allowed to use the axioms for addition and multiplication (e.g. inverse, commutativity, associativity, cancellation, distributivity) :)